# Activerecord field validation one after the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, callback

I would like to know how do you validate a field after passing other validations, for example, I have:

```
validates_numericality_of :field
validates_inclusion_of :field (after validating field's numericality)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a custom validation method for this.

This is how I would do it:

```
validate :custom_inclusion

private

def custom_inclusion
    range = (1..100)
    begin
      Kernel.float(field)
    rescue ArgumentError
      errors.add(:field,"is not a number") and return
    end

    if !(range.min < field.to_i && range.max > field.to_i)
      errors.add(:field,"is not between #{range.min} and #{range.max}")
    end
end
```

where `field` is a model attribute you want to validate.

Comment: thanks a lot. my other alternative is to append `:if => :non_zero` option on `validate_inclusion_of` validation because the fields converts the value to 0 (zero) when a non-numeric value is assigned to it.